# changed background when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main menu. when i click or hover there is a background color. But when i go to the next level menu the background color gets back.

here is the code:

```
$('.main-menus > ul > li > a').on('click',function(){
    $('.tmain-subs').hide();
    $(this).closest('.toggle > li > a').toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

I have tried to use the .next() the show the next element when I click but I am not really sure if I get this right thing to use. How can i let the background color keep active when im on the lower level menu?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/374wbopa/)

Comment: i dont get what you want to achieve.

Comment: @timotheusTriebl i wanted the blue background on the "main menu" to stay in the background while it was clicked when it's submenus is shown. then the background be gone with clicked on the second main menu. But what it is now is that I wont work  it only works on hover.

Comment: @zeratops i have posted the link of jsfiddle named "demo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.main-menus > ul > li > a').on('click',function(){
    $('.tmain-subs').hide();
    $(this).closest('.toggle > li > a').toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).next().show();
    $('.main-menus > ul > li > a').removeClass('on');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Check this code, what i did was removing class for active elements and activate the current clicked element.

Comment: this is what I am looking for! I tried this earlier but maybe I messed up the code that is why it is not working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to remove the default margin of the `<ul>` inside your main menu.

```
 .main-menus ul {
   width: 340px; 
   height: 100vh;
   border-left: 1px solid #0a92fc; 
   background: #e0e9eb; 
   margin:0;
 }
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/374wbopa/2/

Answer (score 1):

I solved your issue, just replace your jquery code with following :-

```
$('.main-menus > ul > li > a').on('click',function(){
    $('.tmain-subs').hide();
    $('.main-menus > ul > li > a').removeClass("on");
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have updated your fiddle also, Please let me know is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$(this).toggleClass('on');` in your jQuery file and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
$('.main-menus > ul > li > a').each(function () {
      $(this).css("background","");
});
$(this).css("background","#0a92fc");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/374wbopa/11/)

Comment: toggleClass('on'); and removeClass("on"); are better solutions

Comment: this works too. thanks.. but i wonder where you all guys get "on" though. i'm guessing its the hover.. :)

Comment: ^^ im just copy and paste,sorry i didnt check it.
But i think you know what to do now